# How to create a text file for each files found in a directory?

Tags: linux, files, for, text

I'm new to unix and I'm having a hard time doing this loop.

I have a directory with a list of files and I'm able to list all of those files in a text file.

I have a text file that contains the following contents:

- FileName01.xml
- FileName02.xml
- FileName03.xml
- FileNameNN.xml

I want to create a text file separately for each of those contents. The output should be like this:

-File name of the text file: Filename01.txt
-Content of the text file: FileName01.xml

And so on and so forth

I'm trying using for loop to create a text file for each of those contents and I can't seem to make it.

This is the current script that I'm working on:

```
#!/bin/bash
ls /directory/input > filelist.txt
for f in filelist.txt;
do
    printf f > 'file_*.txt'
done
```

Comment: `for f in $(ls /directory/input);do echo $f > ${f}.txt; done `   Is this the answer you need? I use a translation software, can understand the wrong question

Comment: @山河以无恙 please don't use `$(ls)`: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead ; also, even if it worked reliably, it would be less useful than `for f in /directory/input/* ; …`, which is nicer..

Answer (score 2):

I suggest

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob

for f in /directory/input/*.xml; do
  bn=${f##*/}
  printf '%s\n' "$bn" > "${f%.xml}.txt"
done
```

See [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) for an explanation of the prefix and suffix removal syntax.